Can't update UI of Form when trigger event to load Form with panel control
I have a problem when using the panel to load content of form via trigger an event.
My struct of app includes:
Home Form: includes 3 Forms (Form A, Form B and Form C). It can load via the left side menu.
When I click on menu A or menu B or menu C: The main panel of Home form will be load the content of Form A or Form B or Form C.
In the Form A, I have 3 child forms (A1 Form, A2 Form, A3 Form): Default when the Form A loaded. The content panel of Form A will be load A1 Form and show it.
I update the content panel via trigger an event. It's can change from A1 Form to A2 Form and A3 Form and Reset to A1 Form.
In my code, When the panel add new form, I will be clean the prev form and close it to reduce memory usaged.
My problem:
When my event has trigger, the content panel of Form A has add a new form but the UI of A1 Form not update or not show A2 Form, A3 Form, It still show A1 Form if I trigger change to A2 Form or A3 Form.
But when I has use more event to trigger, the UI has update normaly. I don't want use this solution for my app. Please help me. Thanks so much.
Sorry if my English not good to present.
How to produce this case:
When AForm active I will register event bus, and unregister when AForm closed
Ex: When has an event trigger : App will call EventBus.Instance.PostEvent("READ_CARD_STEPS.FINISH"); to push event to AForm subcriser, after that call InitFormContent(new A1Form(this.pnVerifyContentBox)); to load A1Form
I can't update UI on A1Form,  I wanna change text of label and show it
 private void updateUIShowMessage(string message)
  {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
                {
                    this.lbCardMessage.Visible = true;
                    this.lbCardMessage.Text = message;
                    this.rdMessageCard.Visible = true;
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                this.lbCardMessage.Visible = true;
                this.lbCardMessage.Text = message;
                this.rdMessageCard.Visible = true;
                this.lbCardMessage.Refresh(); // Label not update or show
                this.rdMessageCard.Refresh(); // Can't refresh UI
                AppLog.Instance.Write("updateUIShowMessage: " + message);
            }
 }

The InitFormContent func will call this func
FormAction.Instance.LoadContentForm(contentF, this.pnVerifyContentBox, true);

this.pnVerifyContentBox: The content panel of Form A
contentF: new Form need to load
This is my code:
public void LoadContentForm(Form f, Panel pnContainer, bool isCleanForm)
    {
        try
        {
            //Form f = frmChild as Form;
            if (pnContainer == null)
            {
                AppLog.Instance.Write("LOAD FORM " + f?.ToString() + " BUT ERROR: pnContainer is null");
                return;
            }

            if (isCleanForm && prevForm != null && (prevForm.Name != "AForm" && prevForm.Name != f.Name))
            {
                AppLog.Instance.Write("-------- CLEAN " + prevForm?.Name?.ToString() + " UI -------------");
                prevForm.Close();
                prevForm.Dispose();
                GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            }

            if (pnContainer?.Controls?.Count > 0)
                pnContainer?.Controls?.RemoveAt(0);
                pnContainer?.Controls?.Clear();
                pnContainer?.Refresh();

            f.TopLevel = false;
            f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            f.Opacity = 100;
            f.Visible = true;

            pnContainer?.Controls.Add(f);
            pnContainer.Tag = f;
            pnContainer.Visible = true;
            currentPanel = pnContainer;
            prevForm = f;
            f.Show();

            AppLog.Instance.Write("CURRENT ACTIVE PANEL: " + pnContainer?.Controls[0].Name + " and Active Form: " + f.Name);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AppLog.Instance.Write("LOAD FORM " + f?.ToString() + " BUT ERROR: " + ex.Message.ToString());
        }

    }

Some logs when I tracing:
\\\\\\\[16:06:21.750\\\\\\\]: AForm OnEventBus: CARD_STATUS.EMPTY

\\\\\\\[16:06:21.752\\\\\\\]: RESET SCAN CARD DATA

\\\\\\\[16:06:21.753\\\\\\\]: RESET SCAN CARD INFO

\\\\\\\[16:06:21.755\\\\\\\]: RESET SCAN CARD STATE

\\\\\\\[16:06:21.757\\\\\\\]: RESET CARD VERIFY INFO

\\\\\\\[16:06:21.759\\\\\\\]: AForm OnEventBus: RESET_CARD_COMPLETED

\\\\\\\[16:06:21.760\\\\\\\]: A1Form InitializeComponent

\\\\\\\[16:06:21.832\\\\\\\]: CURRENT ACTIVE PANEL: A1Form and Active Form: A1Form

\\\\\\\[16:06:21.996\\\\\\\]: STOP TIMER PRVENT CALL VERIFY CARD

\\\\\\\[16:06:22.646\\\\\\\]: AForm OnEventBus: READ_CARD_STEPS.SCANCARD

\\\\\\\[16:06:22.716\\\\\\\]: updateUIShowMessage: Start Scan Card

\\\\\\\[16:06:23.034\\\\\\\]: AForm OnEventBus: READ_CARD_STEPS.CONNECT_CARD

\\\\\\\[16:06:23.456\\\\\\\]: updateUIShowMessage: Start Connect Card

\\\\\\\[16:06:23.591\\\\\\\]: AForm OnEventBus: READ_CARD_STEPS.READ_DGS

\\\\\\\[16:06:23.821\\\\\\\]: updateUIShowMessage: Start read dgs

\\\\\\\[16:06:25.310\\\\\\\]: AForm OnEventBus: READ_CARD_STEPS.FINISH

\\\\\\\[16:06:25.311\\\\\\\]: updateUIShowMessage: Read card finish

\\\\\\\[16:06:25.313\\\\\\\]: AForm OnEventBus: READ_CARD_STATUS.SUCCESS

\\\\\\\[16:06:25.315\\\\\\\]: GO TO A2Form

\\\\\\\[16:06:25.323\\\\\\\]: -------- CLEAN A1Form UI -------------

\\\\\\\[16:06:25.339\\\\\\\]: CURRENT ACTIVE PANEL: A2Form and Active Form: A2Form

\\\\\\\[16:06:25.341\\\\\\\]: A2Form SHOW

\\\\\\\[16:06:25.343\\\\\\\]: RESET CARD VERIFY INFO

\\\\\\\[16:06:25.345\\\\\\\]: AForm OnEventBus: FACE_CAPTURE_STATUS.RESET

\\\\\\\[16:06:27.275\\\\\\\]: FACE CAPTURE SUCCESS

\\\\\\\[16:06:27.276\\\\\\\]: CAPTURE FACE CLOSED

\\\\\\\[16:06:27.278\\\\\\\]: AForm OnEventBus: FACE_CAPTURE_STATAUS.SUCCESS

\\\\\\\[16:06:27.280\\\\\\\]: START TIMER PRVENT CALL VERIFY CARD

\\\\\\\[16:06:27.287\\\\\\\]: CALL API TO VERIFY ID CARD

\\\\\\\[16:06:27.578\\\\\\\]: VERIFY CARD SUCCESS WITH AUTO CALL VERIFY

\\\\\\\[16:06:27.580\\\\\\\]: AForm OnEventBus: SCAN_CARD_DONE

\\\\\\\[16:06:27.582\\\\\\\]: STOP TIMER PRVENT CALL VERIFY CARD

\\\\\\\[16:06:27.583\\\\\\\]: SHOW CARD INFO COMPLETED SCANNED FROM SCAN STEP

\\\\\\\[16:06:27.585\\\\\\\]: A3Form InitializeComponent

\\\\\\\[16:06:27.594\\\\\\\]: -------- CLEAN A2Form UI -------------

\\\\\\\[16:06:27.595\\\\\\\]: A2Form_FormClosed

\\\\\\\[16:06:27.597\\\\\\\]: CAPTURE FACE CLOSED

\\\\\\\[16:06:27.618\\\\\\\]: CURRENT ACTIVE PANEL: A3Form and Active Form: A3Form

\\\\\\\[16:06:27.634\\\\\\\]: -------- CLEAN A3Form UI -------------

\\\\\\\[16:06:28.030\\\\\\\]: A1Form InitializeComponent

My expectation: I wanna update UI of the form via the panel with any an event has trigger and clean memory if the form not active.
